# Validation accuracy is too low with Xception model while it is all okay with my own model

Tags: python, tensorflow

[image: Losses and accuracies with modified Xception model]

[image: Losses and accuracies with modified my model]

I got the results in the first image with Xception, and the second one with my simple convolutional model. (UrbanSound8k) Moreover, evaluating with training dataset gave me a very low accuracy.

https://github.com/A-H4NU/RnEAI/blob/a4a66e12a913c6a6660ced8160d65bcf4330fba9/CNN/urbansound_classification_tf_data.ipynb

This is a link for the whole code.

I generated "my model" with this function

```py
def get_model1():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        InputLayer(input_shape=(img_height, img_width, channels)),
        ZeroPadding2D(padding=1),
        Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(4,3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        Conv2D(filters=13, kernel_size=(4,3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dropout(rate=0.5),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(rate=0.3),
        Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
    return model
```

and Xception model with

```py
def get_model3():
    xception = tf.keras.applications.Xception(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",
                                              input_shape=input_shape, classes=n_class)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        xception,                  
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_class, activation = 'softmax'),
    ])
    return model
```

I could not found any problem with my code, so could you please point out what's wrong with the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xception I believe requires the pixel values to be in the range -1 to +1. Did you scale the pixels? Try

```
img=img /127.5 - 1
```

also in Xception you do not need to set classes since you set include_top=False
Try using this code:

```
base_model=xception = tf.keras.applications.Xception(include_top=False, 
                    weights="imagenet", input_shape=input_shape,pooling=max)
x=basemodel.output
x= Dense(256,activation='relu)(x)
x= Dropout(rate=.4)(x)
output= Dense(n_class, activation='softmax)(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                metrics= ['accuracy'])
```